# Firebase Realtime is taking too long on first read

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a bot for Discord (in Python) and I'm using Firebase to store some information. Until last week the bot was reading in a few milliseconds, but now it's taking a few minutes. I've already purchased the Blaze plan, but I still can't read my database quickly. What could have happened?

```py
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
import json, discord, firebase_admin, time

cred = credentials.Certificate('database/yyyyy.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'databaseURL': 'https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/'})

def read(guild_id, member_id, ref):
    JsonData = db.reference(f'{guild_id}/{member_id}/{ref}')
    return JsonData.get()

game_data = {}
game_data = read("", "", "")
```

Comment: There is no performance difference for the Realtime Database between the free and paid plans of your Firebase project. What does the load of your database in the Firebase console look like?

Comment: It's a small database with just two test keys... I've also tested it without any data and it takes 2min to read.

Comment: As I said, until last week the reading was being done in a few milliseconds, but now it's taking 2min

Comment: Not sure what could be causing it, as I don't think there were any big changes in the past week(s). It might be worth [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, and possibly also to allow engineering to check on your database.